# Good practice on saving properties in relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logic

Let's assume I have two types of users in my system.

Those who can program and those who cannot.

I need to save both types of users in the same table.
The users who can program have lots properties different to those who can't, defined in another table.

What's either advantages of the following solutions and are there any better solutions?

**Solution 1**

One table containing a column with the correspondig property.

```
Table `users`:
----------------------------
| id | name  | can_program |
----------------------------
| 1  | Karl  | 1           |
| 2  | Ally  | 0           |
| 3  | Blake | 1           |
----------------------------
```

**Solution 2**

Two tables related to each other via primary key and foreign key.
One of the tables containing the users and the other table only containing the id of those who can program.

Table `users`:

```
--------------
| id | name  | 
--------------
| 1  | Karl  |
| 2  | Ally  |
| 3  | Blake |
--------------
```

Table `can_program`:

```
---------------------
| id | can_program  | 
---------------------
| 1  | 1            |
| 3  | 1            |
---------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a 1-1 relationship between a user and the property that allows him to program. I would recommend storing this information as an additional column in table `users`. Creating an additional table will basically results in an additional storage structure with a 1-1 relationship to the original table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have some kind of `programmer_profiles` table that the `users` table has a one-to-many relationship with?

If there's an associated record in `programmer_profiles` then they can program, otherwise it's presumed they can't.

This is more flexible since you can add in other `x_profiles` tables that provide different properties even if some of these have the same names.

Comment: Thanks. How would I join those tables to get a column 'can_program' and a 1 if so but a 0 if not?

Comment: You don't join them that way. This is a one-to-many, as in `programmer_profiles` has some kind of `user_id` column that links back to the `users` table. It becomes `SELECT ... FROM users LEFT JOIN programmer_profiles ON users.id=programmer_profiles.user_id`

Comment: But assuming I'd need to process only those users who can program. How would I write a query to return only those of the kind?
Or would I need to check if `is_teacher` in `programmer_profiles` equals `NULL` or `1`?

Comment: You can use a `RIGHT JOIN` to select only records with matching profiles. `LEFT JOIN` selects all records and includes profiles if present. Relational databases are all about relational data, and that means `JOIN` gets involved heavily.